# Convert binary data to long[] using Inputstream while mainting original order

Tags: java, android, performance, inputstream

### Problem description

I have a file of 2mb which contains only binary data. I only need to convert this file to a `long[]` while maintaining the order the data has in that file. Since the file is read on Android I only have access to the file as an `InputStream`. The final thing that I am desperately trying to accomplish (and also the reason why I put the data in compressed binary data format) is to do it as fast as possible.

### Working code for Android

Since I can't get the `File` on android and can only use a `resource` and represent the file as an InputStream I had to written for my desktop to use an InputStream instead of a file. On my mobile flagship phone it took on average 61ms with this code:

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(context.getResources().openRawResource(fileID));
int bytesOfBinaryFile = dis.available();
byte[] bytes = new byte[bytesOfBinaryFile];
dis.readFully(bytes);
int longCount = bytesOfBinaryFile / 8;
long[] array = new long[longCount];
bytesToLongArray(bytes, array);
```

with `bytesToLongArray(bytes, array)` being:

```
private void bytesToLongArray(byte[] bytes, long[] longs) {
    int numberOfLongs = longs.length;
    int head = 0;
    long l;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLongs; i++) {
        l = ((bytes[head] & 0xFFL) << 56) |
                ((bytes[head + 1] & 0xFFL) << 48) |
                ((bytes[head + 2] & 0xFFL) << 40) |
                ((bytes[head + 3] & 0xFFL) << 32) |
                ((bytes[head + 4] & 0xFFL) << 24) |
                ((bytes[head + 5] & 0xFFL) << 16) |
                ((bytes[head + 6] & 0xFFL) <<  8) |
                ((bytes[head + 7] & 0xFFL) <<  0) ;
        longs[i] = l;
        head += 8;
    }
}
```

### Similar working code for desktop

Just for reference and comparison I include this code. I got it working pretty fast on my desktop (where it only takes about 3.5ms) to load the 2mb file into a `long[]`:

```
String fileName = "example";
FileInputStream fip = new FileInputStream(fileName);
FileChannel fc = fip.getChannel();
double bytesOfBinaryFile = fc.size();
int longCount = (int) bytesOfBinaryFile / 8;
MappedByteBuffer mbb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY,
        0L, fc.size());
LongBuffer lb = mbb.asLongBuffer(); 
long[] array = long[longCount];
lb.get(array);
```

### Question

**I wonder if someone knows a faster way or a way to improve my current method.** I hope there is still room for performance improvements.

Comment: The performance difference is caused mostly because the phone's processor and other hardware components are a lot slower than a PC's hardware. Probably there is a way to make it faster but you will never reach even close to 3.5 seconds.

Comment: @MateiTrandafir That's true. But I thought that maybe someone knew a way to further decrease the time it takes on a mobile smartphone.

Comment: Does the time increase linearly with the file size?

Comment: How do you know that it's the loop that takes long? Maybe it's reading from the file that is slow.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I did not time that yet. I will do that next.

Comment: @CITBL converting the inputStream into a byte[] takes around 45% of the total time. After that the inputStream is not used.

Comment: @Joop I am surprised. I was expecting the time to increase linearly or faster than linearly, indicating whether there were memory management issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be what you are looking for:

```
 ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap (byte[] array);
 LongBuffer longBuffer = byteBuffer.asLongBuffer ()
 long[] longArray =  longBuffer.array();
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#asLongBuffer%28%29

Comment: I will see how fast this is. Thanks for the suggestion @Peter

Comment: Actually you could even use FileChannel to first map the file into memory and than use MappedByteBuffer for the whole operation. This should be really fast.

Comment: You could access your file in android, too, if you would choose to use to deploy them as assets. So if this is an option to you, you can use the AssetManager for retrieving the file descriptor as AssetFileDescriptor, then get the FileInputStream from it, than construct the FileChannel from it and map it into memory.

Comment: That's true. Thank you for pointing that out. The maximum size is 1mb though. I could go into the small hassle to divide the file.

Comment: This solution was significantly faster.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this loop will be faster:

```
for(int i=0; i<bytes.length; ++i) {
  longs[i >> 3] |= (bytes[i] & 0xFFL) <<  ((7-(i & 3))<<3);
}
```

Or if you want to use a different byte order - the first byte to be the lowest in the long - than this one (one subtraction operation less):

```
for(int i=0;i<bytes.length;++i) {
  longs[i >> 3] |= (bytes[i] & 0xFFL) <<  ((i & 3)<<3);
}
```

Note though, that the bytes.length must be divisible by 8, otherwise you need one extra long in the longs array.

Also the longs in the array must be initialized to zeros. But as I know it's done automatically when  you allocate the array.

Comment: This seems to be around 15% slower. :(

Answer (score 1):

Throw it all away, wrap the `InputStream` in a `BufferedInputStream,` wrap that in a `DataInputStream,` and use `readLong().`

Comment: In the hope of a simple and efficient answer I implemented it this way and this takes 210ms instead of the usual 60-70ms.